# Trying to get number out of array getting NaN error

Tags: javascript

Getting an NAN error when trying to get the total of grades in the class.
Tried parseInt() and .value on students[i].grade. I am totally new.

```
var students= [{name:"David", grade:80}, 
               {name:"Vinoth", grade:77}, 
               {name:"Divya", grade:88}, 
               {name:"Ishitha", grade:95},
               {name:"Thomas", grade:68}];


var average;

for(i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    console.log(students[i].grade);
    average += Number(students[i].grade.value);
    console.log(average);
}
```

Output from console log is:

80
NaN
77
NaN
88
NaN
95
NaN
68
NaN

Comment: Just leave value away. students[i].grade already returns a number. Number() is not needed

Comment: What does the `.value` property even mean?

Comment: You know that you're calculating the sum, not the average, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to initialize average: `var average = 0`;

2) You also don't need `.value` since value is not a valid property.

`average += Number(students[i].grade);`

3) You don't need to redundantly cast a number value into a number with `Number()` if you can be sure all accessed properties are already number types.

This will do just fine:

```js
var students= [{name:"David", grade:80}, 
           {name:"Vinoth", grade:77}, 
           {name:"Divya", grade:88}, 
           {name:"Ishitha", grade:95},
           {name:"Thomas", grade:68}];

var average = 0;

for(i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    console.log(students[i].grade);
    average += Number(students[i].grade);
    console.log(average);
}

console.log("average: ", average/students.length);
```

Comment: They also don't need `Number` :-)

Comment: That fixed everything!

Comment: Yes but it does not hurt technically

Comment: Also, this is the sum of all grades not average. :)